# How to use OpenCV with highGUI on QtCreator?

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, raspberry-pi3

I am trying to display a basic image that is loaded off disk using the **highgui** module within the cv2 library.
I am able to do this when making a Qt Widgets application but the Qt window becomes redundant; however when using a console application I obtain this error:

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (size.width>0 && size.height>0) in imshow, file /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 269
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /build/opencv-ISmtkH/opencv-2.4.9.1+dfsg/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp:269: error: (-215) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function imshow
```

Here is my code:

```
int main ()
{ 
    cv::Mat inputImg = cv::imread("/home/pi/scrot1.png");
    cv::imshow("Display Image", inputImg);
}
```

I have written a script in python that can be run via terminal and it calls the high gui module. I would like to write this in C++ but I cannot seem to be able to load a basic image!

**EDIT:**

The path was actually invalid. However, even with the correct path I cannot see the image with HighGui.

Comment: So, your question is not Python related?

Comment: The image path is invalid, so you cannot read the image, nor display it. You'll see that with `inputImg.empty()`.

Comment: I have written script that tracks an object based on a hsv mask and would appreciate a software engineer to highlight key features of the transitional process of quick prototyping in python to performance boosting c++, you see I am trying to maximise my frame rate and I hoped switching to c++ would help

Comment: Thank you Miki, any ideas on how to resolve the issue, the exact same image path is specified in another project where I am using a qt widgets application .. I seem to be missing something?

Comment: Be sure that 1) the image exists and it's not corrupted, 2) the path is correct, 3) you have the privileges to access that folder. Remember to use @Username to notify the user

Comment: Apologies Miki that file WAS invalid, I ammended it to scrot1.png and the error has gone so you were right. HOWEVER, now I have no error and the image still does not load via high gui?

Comment: If the image is correctly loaded, you need to add `cv::waitKey()` after imshow to see the image

Comment: Thank you Miki, you make this website awesome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that the image is not loaded correctly.
You can check this using:

```
if(image.empty()) {
   // not loaded correctly
}
```

You need to be sure that:

1. the path is valid
2. the image is not corrupted
3. you have the privileges to access that folder

---

To actually display the image, you need to use `cv::waitKey()` after the `imshow`.